Easy log for auditing of Firebase database activity (on Flutter)?
I have a relatively simple Flutter app using Firebase dataase. In the last few days I see that there are thousands of write activities done to Firebase and it finishes my 20k daily free quota very quickly.
It was all running smoothly until suddenly it went berserk and I can't find where it sends the write commands.
Is there a relatively easy way to see what queries have been sent to Firebase and how many read/writes/deletes they created?
Thanks,
Nils
